# Why does github prevent zero commit pull requests?

Tags: github

I'm a bit surprised to learn that Github doesn't seem to allow the creation of a pull request between two identical branches.  Is there a rationale to this?  We have been building a workflow using WIP Pull Requests, and not being allowed to do this is annoying.  We want to create the pull request at the beginning, in anticipation of future work to merge.

Is there a way to do it that I'm not seeing?

Comment: "I'm a bit surprised to learn that physics doesn't seem to allow me to pour water into an upside-down water glass. Is there a rationale to this?" Yes, it's because that's not how it works. Turn the glass right-side up first, _then_ try pouring the water. It's all about the order of operations, and using tools the way they're designed.

Comment: You put a lot of effort into that sarcasm.